# Moment generating funtion of gamma random variable

Tags: probability

how would I find the mgf of a gamma rv with parameter k > 0 and λ > 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen $(k, \lambda)$ to parametrize a Gamma distribution before, but I *have* seen $\lambda$ to parametrize an exponential distribution (with mean $1/\lambda$). I am not going to provide a complete solution here, but some hints.

**Hint**: Assuming you've defined a Gamma ($X$) distribution to be the sum of $k$ independent exponential random variables ($Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_k$), each with mean $1/\lambda$, then
$$M_{X}(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{(Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_k)t}\right] = \prod_{i=1}^{k}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{Y_i t}\right]$$
(why?) and now the moment-generating function of an exponentially-distributed random variable is $M_{Y_i}(t) = \dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}$ for $t < \lambda$.